# How to perform pointer arithmetic?

Tags: carbon-lang

I'm new to the Carbon language, how to perform pointer arithmetic? Is this even possible?

```
p = p + 1;

=>

COMPILATION ERROR: <source>:11: type error in `+`:
could not find implementation of interface AddWith(U = i32) for i32*
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: The language still has a long way to go. Once its rolled out and all the bugs/issues are raised, then they will have to fix them. So far I will stick to the C++/C code. I am unable to print two integers or a string and an integer in Carbon on the same line using Print function. I probably just dont know it much

Comment: I think you can use `Print("{0} {1}", myInt, myStr)` to do so, however, I don't see the connection to my question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon does not support pointer arithmetic. The only two operations are

- dereference (`*p` gives the l-value p points to),
- address-of (`&v` gives the address of l-value `v`).

More detail is available in [carbon design notes](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang/tree/trunk/docs/design#pointer-types).